# I get an empty RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to get all the values ​​from the `food` object as well as the `nutrients` that are in `hints`.

```
"hints": [
    {
      "food": {
        "foodId": "food_amqspy5ap567v6bun60usbgsaor7",
        "label": "Nuts",
        "knownAs": "nuts",
        "nutrients": {
          "ENERC_KCAL": 594,
          "PROCNT": 17.3,
          "FAT": 51.45,
          "CHOCDF": 25.35,
          "FIBTG": 9
        },
        "category": "Generic foods",
        "categoryLabel": "food",
        "image": "https://www.edamam.com/food-img/e29/e2985d3585a6950c276e204ba7ba9b2e.jpg"
      },
      "measures": [
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_unit",
          "label": "Whole",
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_pouch",
          "label": "Pouch",
          "weight": 113
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_serving",
          "label": "Serving",
          "weight": 34
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_nut",
          "label": "Nut",
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_bag",
          "label": "Bag",
          "weight": 113
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_container",
          "label": "Container",
          "weight": 113
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_package",
          "label": "Package",
          "weight": 113
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_packet",
          "label": "Packet",
          "weight": 113
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_gram",
          "label": "Gram",
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_ounce",
          "label": "Ounce",
          "weight": 28.349523125
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_pound",
          "label": "Pound",
          "weight": 453.59237
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_kilogram",
          "label": "Kilogram",
          "weight": 1000
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_handful",
          "label": "Handful",
          "weight": 17.125
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_cup",
          "label": "Cup",
          "weight": 137
        }
      ]
    },
```

At the moment I'm trying to get at least the `label` value from `food`, but I can't get anything.

```
    try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hints");
    JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("food");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray1.length() && i < jsonArray2.length() ; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i);

        FoodModels model = new FoodModels();
        model.setName(jsonObject2.getString("label"));

        foodModelsList.add(model);
    }

}
```

FoodAdapter

```
public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final FoodRecyclerViewInterface recyclerViewInterface;
    private Context context;
    private List<FoodModels> mData;

    public FoodAdapter(Context context, List<FoodModels> mData, FoodRecyclerViewInterface recyclerViewInterface) {
        this.recyclerViewInterface = recyclerViewInterface;
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        return new FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder(view, recyclerViewInterface);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, img, kcal, procent, fat, chocdf, fidtg;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, FoodRecyclerViewInterface recyclerViewInterface) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (recyclerViewInterface != null){
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        recyclerViewInterface.onItemClick(pos);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add this list to a Adapter and attached the adapter to a RecyclerView?

Comment: @Alécio Carvalho Yes I did it, with other api it works fine, which doesn't have nested arrays.

Comment: without seeing your adapter it is hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @Alécio Carvalho add adapter code

Comment: `JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("food");` This is wrong. `food` is inside `hints`. I suggest you use a JSON parser library that automatically parses your JSON to a POJO instead of doing it manually.

Comment: @m0skit0 What is the library?

Comment: You can search that for yourself, recommendations are not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hints");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject hintObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject foodObject = hintObject.getJSONObject("food");

        String label = foodObject.getString("label");

        FoodModels model = new FoodModels();
        model.setName(label);

        foodModelsList.add(model);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In order to get the insider JSONObject you have to do this:

```
JSONObject nutrientsObject = foodObject.getJSONObject("nutrients");
    int enercKcal = nutrientsObject.getInt("ENERC_KCAL");
    double procnt = nutrientsObject.getDouble("PROCNT");
    double fat = nutrientsObject.getDouble("FAT");
    double chocdf = nutrientsObject.getDouble("CHOCDF");
    int fibtg = nutrientsObject.getInt("FIBTG");
```

Think about it as a staircase that will be more easier for you.

this is the full code **but not the best solution**:

```
try {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hints");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject hintObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject foodObject = hintObject.getJSONObject("food");
    
    String foodId = foodObject.getString("foodId");
    String label = foodObject.getString("label");
    String knownAs = foodObject.getString("knownAs");
    String category = foodObject.getString("category");
    String categoryLabel = foodObject.getString("categoryLabel");
    String image = foodObject.getString("image");
    JSONObject nutrients = foodObject.getJSONObject("nutrients");
    double enercKcal = nutrients.getDouble("ENERC_KCAL");
    double procnt = nutrients.getDouble("PROCNT");
    double fat = nutrients.getDouble("FAT");
    double chocdf = nutrients.getDouble("CHOCDF");
    double fibtg = nutrients.getDouble("FIBTG");
    
    JSONArray measures = hintObject.getJSONArray("measures");
    
    for (int j = 0; j < measures.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject measure = measures.getJSONObject(j);
        
        String uri = measure.getString("uri");
        String measureLabel = measure.getString("label");
        double weight = measure.getDouble("weight");
        
    }
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> This is all the data inside the hints but do not forget to add them to
> the models.

regards

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please tell me how to get objects from `"nutrients": {
          "ENERC_KCAL": 594,
          "PROCNT": 17.3,
          "FAT": 51.45,
          "CHOCDF": 25.35,
          "FIBTG": 9
        }`

Comment: @soundsofnature Please let me know if you have any error

Comment: I am getting total 9 values ​​in the list

Comment: I don't get the whole list

Comment: @soundsofnature That is normal because you have to complete the code I just demonstrated the way to do that  for just a part

Comment: @soundsofnature Try to create fromMap and toMap methods in your classes to make your code more efficient.

Comment: I can't do it no matter what I do

Comment: @soundsofnature update your question and add what you did so I can see where is the error and help you

Comment: The problem is that there are only 9 `food` values ​​in the hints array itself, and the rest of the `food` values ​​go without an array. It turns out that you need to parse all food values ​​and not just those in `hints`

Comment: @soundsofnature I updated my answer but I do not understand your last comment. so sorry If this is not what you meant and wants me to explain by do it to you.